# curl proxy перебор рабочих

Tags: curl, proxy

Здраствуйте. Есть курл

```
function curl($url,$proxy)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0
            .2564.109 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.ru');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
И вызов  $file = 'proxy_socks_ip.txt';
    $arr = file($file);
    $count = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $auth = curl($link, $arr[$i]);
}
```

В файле имеется 1000 прокси. Вопрос: как сделать так,чтобы в цикле проверялось рабочая ли прокси,и если да - продолжать работу, если нет - отсеивать ее?

Comment: Это не сайт фриланс.ру

Comment: Сами-то какой алгоритм видите?

Comment: думал .............................
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
if( $output) { curl_close($ch);
    return $output;}else  curl_close($ch);
    return false } Но не идет

Comment: В вашем варианте дикие тормоза будут. При попытке curl читать каждый раз файл и в цикле обойти до первой рабочей прокси. Представьте, что первые 905 прокси нерабочие. На каждый запрос курл заново парсить файл, а потом 905 таймайтов ждать, пока 906 прокси не ответит. Не, нормально?

Comment: Вам нужно задуматься о том, что нужно где-то хранить информацию о выбранном прокси, по-хорошему -- ещё и на все прокси хранить информацию о дате последней проверки. Нужно подумать о том, как делать проверки - по расписанию или когда нужно уже запрос делать.

Comment: В вашем варианте у вас уже написано всё. Осталось только понять, что через прокси нужно запрашивать страницу с точно известным контентом (например, на своём сервере/сайте расположить страницу, отдающую всегда текст 12345) и проверить, совпал ли полученный контент с образцом.

Comment: Зачем вы заново пишете $output -- если у вас целая готовая функция есть? Вы понимаете, что за код вы привели в примере?

Comment: Вот как раз этого и не могу понять,как правильно сверить рабоет ли прокси с нужным мне контентом на сайте.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста,у меня ничего не выходит

Comment: Это не сайт фриланс.ру. Если у вас НИЧЕГО не выходит -- вам нечего делать в профессии. Вы не хотите думать, не хотите хоть какой-то фрагмент из моих комментариев взять и разобрать. Идите на фриланс и платите деньги. Это не стыдно, не больно, не страшно.

Comment: да пробовал я,гл результат один и тот же.Я только начал осваивать курл и с прокси первый раз столкнулся.Поэтому и обратился за помощью сюда

Comment: Да если бы только curl. Вы смотрите на свой код и не видите, что у вас в цикле и зачем. Не понимаете, зачем у вас функция и дублируете заново её тело. Не понимаете, как ответ curl сравнить с образом на своём сервере. Не слышали о запуске по расписанию -- куда ни ткни сплошные пробелы. А главное -- нежелание делать самому, разбираться. "Сделайте всё за меня".

Comment: я просто не понимаю,как определить работает ли прокси или нет.Как задать это условие?

Comment: через прокси нужно запрашивать страницу с точно известным контентом (например, на своём сервере/сайте расположить страницу, отдающую всегда текст 12345) и проверить, совпал ли полученный контент с образцом.

Comment: "Я только начал осваивать курл" -- а в другом своём опросе вы говорите, что "курлом пользовался всегда". Может хватит врать-то, а?

Comment: курлом я пользовался на начальном уровне,максимум-механизм авторизации. Это по вашему много освоил? Пользовался и освоил - разные вещи